# PDE of second order

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Can someone tell me what type of equation is this and how would one go about solving it.
\begin{align}
&u_{xx}-u_{tt}=u+\sin \left(\frac{\pi x}{4}\right),\quad x\in (0,2),\, t>0, \\
&u(0,t)=2,\quad u(2,t)=t-2,\quad t>0, \\
&u(x,0)=2,\quad u_{t}(x,0)=x^{3},\quad x\in (0,2).
\end{align}
I know a method of fourier separation of variables and of expanding $u_{xx}-u_{tt}=f(x,t)$ the right hand side into a sine series.
One thing I believe would be useful is to shift the conditions to $u(0,t)=0~and~u(2,t)=0$ , I dont know how to proceed further.

Anyone has any clue?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Let $u(x,t)=v(x,t)+f(x)+tg(x)$; then
$$
v_{xx}+f''(x)+tg''(x)-v_{tt}=v+f(x)+tg(x)+\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{4}\right). \tag{1}
$$
Now choose $f$ and $g$ such that
$$
f''(x)=f(x)+\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{4}\right),\qquad f(0)=2, \qquad f(2)=-2, \tag{2}
$$
and
$$
g''(x)=g(x), \qquad g(0)=0, \qquad g(2)=1. \tag{3}
$$
This reduces the original PDE to
$$
v_{xx}-v_{tt}=v, \tag{4}
$$
$$
v(0,t)=0=v(2,t), \tag{5}
$$
$$
v(x,0)=2-f(x), \tag{6}
$$
$$
v_t(x,0)=x^3-g(x). \tag{7}
$$
In Physics, Eq. $(4)$ is known as [Klein-Gordon equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation). You can use the method of separation of variables to solve it.